# cudaErrorLaunchFailure while trying to run simple templated kernel on a 64bit data type

Tags: c++, cuda

I have this simple kernel code:

```
template<typename T> __global__ void CalcHamming( const T* pData, const uint64_t u64Count, const T Arg, uint32_t* pu32Results )
{
    uint64_t gidx = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

    while ( gidx < u64Count )
    {
        pu32Results[ gidx ] += __popc( pData[gidx] ^ Arg );
        gidx += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    }
}
```

It works correctly unless I use it for a 64 bit unsigned int (uint64_t). In that case I get **cudaErrorLaunchFailure**. I figured that maybe the problem is in **__popc()** which cannot handle 64 bit numbers so i made a specialized function to solve this:

```
template<> __global__ void CalcHamming<uint64_t>( const uint64_t* pData, const uint64_t u64Count, const uint64_t Arg, uint32_t* pu32Results )
{
    uint64_t gidx = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

    while ( gidx < u64Count )
    {
        pu32Results[ gidx ] += __popcll( pData[gidx] ^ Arg );
        gidx += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    }
}
```

However the problem still remains. One thing to note is that my data are not in several arrays, like this:

Array1 (uint32_t): 100 items 
Array2 (uint64_t): 200 items

But instead concatenated in one memory block:

Array: 100 items (uint32_t), 200 items (uint64_t)

And I am doing some pointer arithmetic to launch the kernel on the correct spot. I'm quite sure the calculations are correct. Also note that the above example is a simplified case, i have many more 'subarrays' of various integer types concatenated like this).

My guess is that this might be behind the issue, that CUDA somehow dislikes the alignment of the uint64_t array. However fixing this requires quite a lot of effort and I would like ot be sure it will help before I do it. Or can I fix this just by modifying the kernel somehow? Will there be performance penalties?

Comment: It's not clear to me what do you mean when saying that you have a concatenated array in one memory block. How declared? How filled? Providing a minimum sized code reproducing your problem would help other people help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uint64_t *must* be 8-bytes aligned: see [HERE](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#vector-types__alignment-requirements-in-device-code).

So yes, CUDA "dislikes" misaligned types: it does not run at all with them.

However I think you can avoid to rearrange your data structure externally. It's enough you check and treat as uint32_t (or uint8_t for total generality!) the extremes of the array. That's quite common in optimized kernels, especially using vector types as float4, int4,...

For some alignment tips see [HERE](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory-accesses).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One more question - would the fix I wrote above (having one array for each item instead of one huge concatenated array) fix this problem? I might do that instead of modifying the kernels and handling the extremes in a special way. It seems a bit more robust to me. It should also allow me to drop the specialized kernels.

Comment: "... special care must be taken to maintain alignment of the starting address of any value or array of values of these types. A typical case where this might be easily overlooked is when using some custom global memory allocation scheme, whereby the allocations of multiple arrays (with multiple calls to cudaMalloc() or cuMemAlloc()) is replaced by the allocation of a single large block of memory partitioned into multiple arrays, in which case the starting address of each array is offset from the block's starting address." Which is exactly my case. This also seems to imply the fix should work.

Comment: I think it is safe: from the [second link](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory-accesses) that I posted: "Any address of a variable residing in global memory or returned by one of the memory allocation routines from the driver or runtime API is always aligned to at least 256 bytes."